# How to calculate width of string in px?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

How to calculate width of string in px ? I have panel and I try like (this reference on JPanel)

```
FontMetrics gp = this.getGraphics().getFontMetrics();
int x=gp.stringWidth("test");
```

but getGraphics returns always null because panel isn't visible yet. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: forget the method component.getGraphics() - you don't need it: either you already have a Graphics object (passed over as a parameter, f.i. in paintComponent) which you are supposed to use or you shouldn't want one ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do this in one of the `paint()` or `paintComponent()` methods where the `Graphics` instance exists.

Or you can can create a `BufferedImage` and call `getGraphics()`.